# TeamCity, KotlinDSL: how to pass FTP password

Tags: kotlin, ftp, passwords, teamcity

Recently I bumped into a situation where our TeamCity build config(s) should be composed by the given business logic, not by hand. Kotlin DSL does match our needs perfectly well so I did a .KTS script quite quickly. The only issue I have so far is FTP uploader step, namely the password parameter. All my attempts to put a password a ended with FTP 503 error.

Like this:

```
param("jetbrains.buildServer.deployer.username", "abc")
param("jetbrains.buildServer.deployer.password", "secret-password")
```

or like that (as I googled out that non-secure password parameter is obsolete):

```
param("jetbrains.buildServer.deployer.username", "abc")
param("secure:jetbrains.buildServer.deployer.password", "secret-password")
```

If I put the password manually in TeamCity and examine generated DSL then, I see the password is somehow secured:

```
param("secure:jetbrains.buildServer.deployer.password", "zxx5a3133fc69ef3252") <- "abc" password
param("secure:jetbrains.buildServer.deployer.password", "zxx4469c7c25073dd9f") <- "123" password
```

What is the encoding/encryption used here? Any clue how to pass an arbitrary password (ideally, via %parameter%) in Kotlin DSL scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to add a password into the versioned settings not via *TeamCity UI* (for example, adding settings with Kotlin-based **DSL**), you will need to add the password to TeamCity and get the corresponding token to use in the settings. The token can be generated via the "Generate Token for password" action available in the **Project** | **Actions menu**.

At this time passwords are not inheritable by projects hierarchy. If a setting in a project (a VCS root, OAuth connection, cloud profile) requires a password, the token generated for this password can be used in this project only. For instance, it is not possible to take a generated token and use it ain a similar setting in a subproject. A new token should be generated in this case.If you need to use a secure value in the nested projects, consider adding a [password parameter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/typed-parameters.html) with the secure value and using a [reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/configuring-build-parameters.html) to the parameter in the nested projects.

other way how to generate the token is

```
mvn -Dtext="mysecret" org.jetbrains.teamcity:teamcity-configs-maven-plugin:scramble
```